# Missing f's in HTML paragraph text on Mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm having an issue on a webpage where some f's are missing from words (on mobile browsers only - iPhone + iPad.  The issues are seen on Merriweather font (weight 300), but not seen if I switch to Merriweather 400 or use another font like Arial.

You can see in the picture that I'm able to find the word find through the "find in page" feature, but the 'f' is missing.

*** Note: this has already been fixed and merged by the Merriweather author and merged in Github. Also, SquareSpace is pointing at the latest and greatest fixed font. ***

[image: iPhone screenshot]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hmmm, not sure how this is off-topic.  Thanks to all that jumped in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the [Merriweather font](https://github.com/EbenSorkin/Merriweather). The font was updated on Jan 24 and this is when some people started seeing issues.

The fact that the problem exists across browsers shows that I think. The font is the default font used in Ghost blog theme Casper.

As part of the Merriweather development the fix for this issue is tracked under: https://github.com/EbenSorkin/Merriweather/issues/16 (scheduled to be release on Jan 25 through Google CDN)

Additionally, see these problem reports:

- https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/charachters-disapearing
- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=580824

Answer (score 0):

Try adding extra spacing to the letters.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp